# Quick question about my code can run in the visual studio but not in py.exe

Tags: python

```
val=input('Do you want to convert B-D or D-B or quit: ')
if val=='B-D':
   dec=input('Please enter binary number: ')
   decR=int(dec,2)
   print("The result of decimal number is:",decR)

if val=='D-B':
   binR=int(input('please enter decimal number: '))
   print(bin(binR)[2:])
  

if val=='quit':
   print('Thank you for using')
```

if I run this code in python.exe, it will quit after I input the request binary/decimal number.but it can run in the visual studio and get the result

Comment: Your code runs fine for me.  Please tell us EXACTLY how you are trying to run it.  Are you bringing up a cmd shell?  Are you double-clicking an icon?

Comment: This code runs fine for me too. I ran it with PowerShell and by double-clicking it. Just check if your inputs are correct or not.